# RMI UnmarshalException ClassNotFoundException server only

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I have followed several tutorials on running an RMI application. However, I can't seem to make it work, as I keep getting stuck on the same exception.

I am, at this point only running a **server**, so no client communication is involved.

I have a simple RMI program that consists of:

1. A server class `SortServer`
2. An interface `ISortFactory<T>`
3. An implementation `QuickSortFactory<T>`
4. An `RMIUtils` class
5. A policy file `allpermissions.policy`

**Policy file contents**

```
grant { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

**RMIUtils**

```
static {
    // Set policy
    setPolicy();

    // Set Security manager if not present
    if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    setHost("127.0.0.1");
}

public static void addCodeBaseFor(Class<?> clazz) {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString());
}

public static void setPolicy() {
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", PolicyFileLocator.getLocationOfPolicyFile());
}

public static void setHost(String hostAddress) {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", hostAddress);
}

public static String getHost() {
    return System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname");
}
```

**SortServer**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, AlreadyBoundException {
    RMIUtils.addCodeBaseFor(ISortFactory.class);

    ISortFactory<String> strQSFactory = new QuickSortFactory<String>();
    // Same error: Naming.bind("rmi://"+RMIUtils.getHost()+"/quicksortfactory", strQSFactory);

    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.rebind("quicksortfactory-string", strQSFactory);
}
```

**ISortFactory**

```
public interface ISortFactory<T> extends Remote {
    public ISorter<T> createSorter() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Implementing QuickSortFactory**

```
public class QuickSortFactory<T> extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ISortFactory<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4856366323843718656L;

    public QuickSortFactory() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public ISorter<T> createSorter() throws RemoteException {
        return new QuickSort<T>();
    }
}
```

**ISorter, QuickSorter and referenced objects**
`ISorter` extends `Remote` and its methods throw `RemoteException`s.
`QuickSort` extends `SortLogic` and implements `ISorter`. Its methods throw `RemoteException`s.
`SortLogic` extends `UnicastRemoteObject`. Its methods throw `RemoteException`s.

Since I use JDK 1.5+, I shouldn't need to worry about stubs.
The rmiregistry is running fine, or I would have different errors.

**Literal console output**

```
2013-11-20 00:57:00 DEBUG RMIUtils:33 - Policy file path changed to 'C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\rmi-sorter5248481413010560777.policy'
2013-11-20 00:57:00 DEBUG RMIUtils:38 - RMI hostname set to 127.0.0.1
2013-11-20 00:57:00 DEBUG RMIUtils:27 - Codebase path added: file:/F:/Development/Git/Personal/parallel-sorter/bin/
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.marktielemans.rmisorter.server.factory.ISortFactory
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at nl.marktielemans.rmisorter.server.SortServer.main(SortServer.java:42)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.marktielemans.rmisorter.server.factory.ISortFactory
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:390)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.marktielemans.rmisorter.server.factory.ISortFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:709)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:653)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:590)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1491)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    ... 12 more
```

**Without codebase parameter**

I've tried without codebase parameter, but am not sure how to include the classes in the RMI classpath as I read I should.

I've tried starting the registry from the code in `SortServer` using `RegistryLocator.getRegistry()` as above, as well as starting it from a command line opened in my `bin` directory. Still, I would get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.marktielemans.rmisorter.server.factory.ISortFactory
...
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
```

The Registry doesn't have that class available in its CLASSPATH.

If you're using the `java.rmi.server.codebase` property you need to set it before exporting any remote objects, and the codebase needs to be something the Registry and the clients can use.

```
public static void addCodeBaseFor(Class<?> clazz) {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString());
}
```

This isn't going to work. The location on the server of the containing JAR file can't be seen from the client. Generally it is an http: or ftp: URL.

Comment: However, I get this error starting the server. Anyway, how should I make this path available then? All examples I have seen just use the abspath for development.

Comment: You get this error binding the server to the Registry. See the stack trace. The parts I quoted prove it. I've answered your other question: HTTP or FTP. All the examples you've seen are wrong if that's what they do. It can only work within the same host.

Comment: The used host is 127.0.0.1. Localhost. Everything is running locally, so that should work, no?

Comment: Probably, but what's the point? My recommendation is to leave the codebase feature strictly alone until you have a working application, and then treat it as a deployment option. Getting an unrealistic configuration like this to work is of zero practical use or interest.

Comment: I'd be happy to get anything to work, even locally. I editted my answer to show how I tried without codebase.

Comment: I got it wo work now by starting RMI from the binary folder. By the time I get to deployment, I'll have to look into fixing the codebase. Thanks providing your insights which helped me fix this.